# Does anyone have Region monitoring working on iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, region

I have an app prototype that was working on Iphone4 + iOS 4.3, build with Xcode 4.02 and iOS4.3 SDK. The app was quite simple, there were 10 registered regions (radius 500m, accuracy 1km), and an app was showing local notifications with messages when entering or exiting those regions. The regions are places in city, all in about 5km radius circle. When testing on iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3, I have been receiving didEnterRegion/didExitRegion delegate method calls when was driving with a car and crossing defined regions boundaries.

However, several weeks later, after updating my stuff to Xcode4.2 and iOS5 in iPhone 4, I'm no longer receiving didEnterRegion/didExitRegion delegate calls when driving through the same tracks in city and testing with device. I have read Apple docs and other post and I know that you need to go quite further from the spots in order to cross region boundaries and to receive callbacks, but it's not my case, because I was testing with ~4 km distance and with the same stuff. Just wondering, does anyone has a real working case when building with iOS 5.0 SDK?

PS. I have set locationManagers delegate property to proper class object to receive delegate calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long debugging, searching and testing I have noticed that it's OK with iOS 5.0 but the real problem with region monitoring is an accuracy. By saying that I mean the location accuracy is very unreliable when using GSM method (1 - 3 km desiredAccuracy), and you might expect to receive as high as 8.5 accuracy error (horizontalAccuracy) when using regions with 5 km radius and 1km desiredAccuracy. I have posted a detailed description of my performed test scenarios and the results of them ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034201/is-it-possible-to-use-only-region-monitoring-gsm-and-to-get-not-more-than-5-km))