# startMonitoringForRegion and iOS5: is accuracy better compared to iOS4?

Tags: gps, ios5, location

Can this method use background GPS for this operation ?
I remember that on iOS4, the method was not very accurate (based on cell location)...
Any detailled information available ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034201/is-it-possible-to-use-only-region-monitoring-gsm-and-to-get-not-more-than-5-km][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034201/is-it-possible-to-use-only-region-monitoring-gsm-and-to-get-not-more-than-5-km

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : No, but....
Long answer  : Region monitoring works on cell+wifi analyzing by default , but by specifying a bigger radius , your app gets a callback (even if it's not suspended at the moment).

From my experience , you can use region monitoring just to cross a specific boundaries , and after entering a region you can "boost" location accuracy by using `startUpdatingLocation` + setting desired accuracy.

note: you should enter your code in `application:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well , for the case where your app is not running, and of course stop updating location when crossing a boundary/recognizing an event that should return your app to previous "region monitoring" state, to conserve battery  power.